# JavaFX, best node/tools to use for this task?

Tags: javafx

i'm developing as a University project a destkop program that handles restaurant menu's management.

Since i'm new to JavaFX, i don't have knowledge of the various tools i can use. I'll provide a mock up of what i want to create with explanations.

[image: Mock up]

The big rounded rectangles are my 'Categories', so 'Appetizers' and 'First Course' (in my mock up they're in italian, so i'm translating). I want this rectangles to be clickable so they can expand and show the meals they have inside.

By pressing the + button, i want to create a category.

Since my program have to be about organizing the menu, i also want to click the - button and enter a "delete" mode, where checkboxes appear on the left side of both categories and meals, i can select them and pressing 'Confirm' deletes them.

I also want to press the '=' button to order my categories (maybe i want to put Appetizers after First Course, or move meals inside a category).

What do you think is the best tools/library/node i can use to deal with this problem? I've looked up a lot but only found out about TitledPanes or Accordions, but seems to static for what i have to do.

Comment: I asked because, since i'm not an expert, maybe there could be MANY more viable options to deal with this problem. I'm already using SceneBuilder and reading the Oracle tutorials.

Comment: Thank you. Another question, can i move the titledpanes' position inside the accordion at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

> there could be MANY more viable options to deal with this problem.

Understandable, but there are not.

You can be confident that you have the best advised solution to your problem by selecting `TitledPane`s or an `Accordion`.

To learn to use these controls, you can prototype using SceneBuilder. You can study layouts in the Oracle tutorials.

> Accordions, but seems to static for what i have to do.

See Accordion [`getPanes()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html#getPanes()) javadoc:

> Changing this ObservableList will immediately result in the Accordion updating to display the new contents of this ObservableList.

so the content is dynamic, not static.

> can i move the titledpanes' position inside the accordion at runtime?

The order in the pane list determines the order of the displayed panes in the Accordion.  Changing the order in the list will automatically change the displayed order, as it is an observed list.